# AWS DynamoDB getitem takes nearly 3 seconds for some calls

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

As part of my project requirement, I am using AWS DynamoDB for caching and as an initial configuration I have configured our read/write units as 5 each and autoscale enabled till 40K. It was working perfectly fine in initial days and I was getting cache response time in 2 digits. But when I increased the traffic, response time started spiking till 3seconds at times. But when i checked cloud watch, read was not showing beyond the border(5). When i checked latency in cloud watch, i was not able to find any value more than 100ms. Can you please look in to the issue and provide a solution for my problem? The surprising thing is that the response time hikes are reaching till 3 seconds only for 99% times.

Expected results: Response time always in 2 digits.

Comment: can you please share aws console screenshots, otherwise there is nothing much to debug here :P

Comment: CloudWatch will show an average metric over a period of time, but requests might be spiking higher for short periods. I would recommend temporarily increasing the Read Capacity Units just to check if this fixes things. Very little cost involved for such a test.